# How to make progress bar focus on most recent value set?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the middle of producing a calories tracker. My users can set weight loss goals and then use the exercise calorie calculator to find out how many calories they've lost from particular exercises. I've produced a progress bar to show users their progress, however the progress bar does this for all of the users goals combined, not the most recent goal set.

How could I set my progress bar to focus on just the most recent goal set by the user?

This is what I have so far

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","registration"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
}


$bar_length = 500;
$bar_height = 40;


$sql = "SELECT 
      SUM(calories) as calories
      , CASE g.weightunit
          WHEN 'lbs' THEN 3500
          ELSE 7700
        END * weightlost as target_calories
    FROM goal g 
        INNER JOIN tracklog t USING (userid)
    WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['userid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($calories, $target);
$res = $stmt->fetch();


function progress_bar($width, $height, $calories, $target)
{
    $bar = "<p style='padding-left: 30px'>"."<svg width='$width' height='$height' align='center' view_box='0 0 $width $height'>\n
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='$width' height='$height' align='right' fill='#CCC' />\n";
// calc width of bar for calories already burned
if ($target==0) {
        $target = 1;
}
if ($calories > 0) {
    $cal_width = $calories * $width / $target;
    $bar .= "<rect x='0' y='0' align='center' width='$cal_width' height='$height' stroke='#ccc' fill='#55d5e7' />\n";
}
else {
    $bar .= "<text x='5' y='16' align='center' font-size='9pt'>No data for user</text>\n";
}
$bar .= "</svg>\n";
return $bar;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>


<p align="center" class="font-3" style="font-size: 16px"><br><br >Calories burned to date : <?=$calories?><br>
Target calories : <?=$target?><br>
<?= progress_bar($bar_length, $bar_height, $calories, $target) ?>
```

Comment: you will need to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in your query

Comment: Where would I put these in my query?

Comment: after your `WHERE` statement you would put somehting like `ORDER BY g.created_date DESC      LIMIT 0,1` now since I don't know what you have in your `goal` table that would allow you to sort this you will need to change the `created_date` to a field that will get you their latest goal

Comment: From my goal table I saved the weight loss goal under weightlost. I've just tried this but it hasn't worked :/